# Spring MVC with Java based config - 404 not found for static resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying out Spring MVC with java config and I'm getting 404 not found for static resources, the folder of which I can confirm is definitively getting published to the server. It seems like the resources are not being resolved at all. So even when calling localhost:8080/SpringMVC/resources/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js I get 404 not found. I'm using Spring 4.0.1

Deployed structure

```
SpringMVC/
   resources/
      css/
      js/
         jquery-1.4.2.min.js  
   WEB-INF/
      classes/
      lib/
      views/ 
         services.jsp
      web.xml
```

My Code:

com/me/config/WebApplicationConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.me.services"})
public class WebApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String VIEW_RESOLVER_SUFFIX = ".jsp";
    private static final String VIEW_RESOLVER_PREFIX = "/WEB-INF/views/";

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        resolver.setPrefix(VIEW_RESOLVER_PREFIX);
        resolver.setSuffix(VIEW_RESOLVER_SUFFIX );
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

        return resolver;
    }
}
```

com/me/config/Initializer.java

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING = "/";
    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(WebApplicationConfig.class);
        rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        servlet.addMapping(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING );
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

com/me/controller/ServicesController.java

```
@Controller
public class ServicesController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String services(ModelMap model) {
        return "services";
    }
}
```

WEB-INF/views/services.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>    
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Services</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

GET Request Response when calling localhost:8080/SpringMVC/:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/SpringMVC/resources/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Services</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

And then after that 404 Not Found on:

```
localhost:8080/SpringMVC/resources/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js
```

Comment: Your deployed structure has a folder named 'jss' and the url you are trying to access has 'js'.Could that be the problem ?

Comment: Sorry that was a spelling mistake in my question - fixed now

Comment: You mean was that the issue ? Is your problem solved ?

Comment: No, it was just a spelling mistake in the question - the actual problem was having double quotes in the jstl as answered below. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think in your `services.jsp`, could you try with single quotes:

```
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js' />"></script>
```

It seems like a problem with 2 sets of double quotes in `<script>`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that but seems like it wasn't the main problem - I edited the question to include the GET request response and from there  it looks like the src url is fine. But the GET to the js file URL returns 404 Not Found

Comment: My bad - single quotes did fix the problem! My mistake while testing was that I was trying to pull a different version file - e.g. jquery-1.11.0.min.js. It works now. Thanks!